# Wordpress: 500 Internal Server Error, probable issue using $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

I'm using Wordpress and I'm performing a query which gives me back this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

My query looks like:

```
global $wpdb;
        $session_uid = isset($_POST["session_uid"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["session_uid"])) : "";
        $the_data = isset($_POST["the_data"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["the_data"])) : "";
        $ss = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages inner join ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users on ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.message_id and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.group_id where ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_username = '$session_uid' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_del = '0' or ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_username = '$session_uid' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_del = '0' group by ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id";
        $check_last_conversation = $wpdb->get_results($ss);
        $response = print $check_last_conversation;
```

I'm probably missing or misunderstanding something but if I comment out `$check_last_conversation` and I `print` something like "Hello", the error goes away.

This is ok:

```
global $wpdb;
    $session_uid = isset($_POST["session_uid"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["session_uid"])) : "";
    $the_data = isset($_POST["the_data"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["the_data"])) : "";
    //$ss = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages inner join ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users on ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.message_id and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.group_id where ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_username = '$session_uid' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_del = '0' or ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_username = '$session_uid' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_del = '0' group by ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id";
    //$check_last_conversation = $wpdb->get_results($ss);
    $response = print 'hello';
```

So I suppose there is some problems on how I've written my query.

```
$ss = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages inner join ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users on ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.message_id and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.group_id where ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_username = '$session_uid' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_del = '0' or ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_username = '$session_uid' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_del = '0' group by ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id";
```

Said that, I can't see the error.

- My `apache_error.log` and `mysql_error_log.err` don't report anything
  about.
- My tables are empty at now but should they print nothing than produce that error.

Can you please suggest something?

**EDIT**

I see this error in my console

[image]

MySQL table empty

[image]

My Wordpress Debug is active like:

[image]

My `debug.log` file (wp-content) is not showing any error in my code.

---

I've discovered that there is a fatal error in the same file of my query:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function `get_bloginfo()`

I could check it trough the **server php error log**. Working on MAMP you can find it here:

> MAMP/logs/php_error.log

In my case, Wordpress didn't report it in `wp-content/debug.log`. So you know. It takes me to the conclusion that my file.php doesn't recognise wordpress hooks and could happen for $wpdb too, throughout my query.

Comment: change `$response = print $check_last_conversation;` to `print_r$check_last_conversation);`

Comment: @ArshSingh tried but nothing! I get the same.

Comment: read my answer below.

Comment: The result that you get is in array. Using `json_encode()` might resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you checked your server error logs?

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh Thanks for your answer, I've tried but nothing!

Comment: @MindaugasM. Yes I'm now checking my php server log. There is something there to fix! I'll write something once I'll fix everything. Thanks!

Comment: @XiLab, please don't forget to share where was the problem.

Comment: @MindaugasM. Thanks after a lot of tweaking I've discovered that there is a fatal error in my file > PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() How do I fix it?

Comment: @XiLab, try to load `wp-blog-header.php` before you call `get_bloginfo();`. Example: `if (!function_exists('get_bloginfo')) require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');` You can check answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41221/wp-enviroment-problem-with-included-file#41229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**During the development** always turn on the error reporting to be aware of `warnings` `notice` or `fatal errors` which can occur very easily if you forget something or miss place something. So better to be aware or errors and turn the error reporting on to see the errors and when in production do disable the error reporting.

> go into wp-config.php file and search for : **define('WP_DEBUG',false);**  and change it to **define('WP_DEBUG',true);**

Even if your query is okay , you will still result to an error , which you will be getting due to incorrect printing of an array:

function `get_results` of `$wpdb` , is an function that will return an array as result of multi rows , and for dumping it use :

```
print_r($check_last_conversation);
```

or

```
var_dump($check_last_conversation);
```

`print 'hello;` works because it is a string , and `$check_last_conversation` is an array. Don't wrap the `print_r` or `var_dump` or `print` or `echo` inside an variable. as they are supposed to print the data inside from variables.

so in case you have more errors , you can look at the errors , by turning the error reporting on.

Comment: I've tried everything you've suggested, I'm even using query monitor to check all my php warnings and issues, but nothing! I'm a kind of lost.

Comment: please do turn on error reporting and post the error you get on your screen. Follow the guide in my answer about turning the debug on in wordpress

Comment: @XiLab please turn the debug on , that error means something is wrong with your code, but what is wrong ,we can know when you turn on the debug  , by going into : wp-config.php file

Comment: Ok, but my debug.log is empty! I don't know how and where to check more. I mean I register errors through define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); and I've nothing! I can post that but it's empty.

Comment: @XiLab not the `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` change `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: I have all 3 the options true. Nothing is displaying or reporting a bug! Look at my screenshot in the question!

Comment: After a lot of tweaking I discover that in my server php error log there is a fatal error in that file! >> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() how can I fix it?

Comment: @XiLab i cannot see `get_bloginfo` anywhere in your posted code.

Comment: I know, but there are other pieces of code in that file. Being an external script integrated with Wordpress I guess it doesn't read Wordpress hooks themselves. This could be the reason why it doesn't recognise get_bloginfo() and could happen the same for $wpdb. Damn. The weird thing it's that all the folder is already located in mytheme/script/... it should take it...

Comment: @XiLab Use `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` and 
 `include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';`. This will include all wordpress functionality for your external script. If it does solve your problem, lemme know and I will post it as answer.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh that's great! Let me try!

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] doesn't work!

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh YES! I've fixed thanks to your suggestion. I was missing a /... I need a coffee... :D Let's write an answer! Thanks again.

Comment: @XiLab Glad to know you have solved your query. I will post is as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

As OP mentioned that he is working on external wordpress script and is not able to access his wordpress functionality. To ensure that you retain your wordpress functionality on your external files, please put the following code, at the start of your external script page.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
```

The above lines, will include all the wordpress functionality for your script. `$path` variable stores the path of your wordpress installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of going on from Ajit's answer. I was also having issues similar to this that was caused by character collation which was fixed by adding one extra line.

At the top of any php external file that used wpdb I was using the following:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
global $wpdb;
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
```

You can then use the $charset_collate in your sql statement, e.g.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$wpdb->base_prefix}my_nice_table` (
      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
```

Hope that helps!