# Can't update data in mysql database (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update data in my database from WP website page using "select" value.

This is how my "select" look like:

```
<select onchange="getState(this.value)" name="state_selector1" id="state_selector1">
```

Here is my JS script:

```
function getState(ns) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/getVal.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "newState=" + ns,
        success: function(output) {
            alert("Статус статьи изменен. " + output);
        }, error: function() {
          alert('Something went wrong.');
        }
    });
};
```

And getVal.php:

```
<?php

    global $wpdb;

    $newState = $_GET['newState'];
    $intNewState = (int)$newState;
    var_dump($intNewState);
    $stateUpdate = $wpdb->update( 'application',
        array( 'state' => $intNewState ),
        array( 'id' => 1 )
    );

?>
```

I get 500 Internal server error every time I change value of "select".
JS gets select value with no problem, as well as PHP, but I get error when I add "$wpdb->update" or "$wpdb->query" in getVal.php.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786757/wordpress-500-internal-server-error-probable-issue-using-wpdb like

Answer (score 0):

Probably You don't have $wpdb object.

Is this your complete file getVal.php? Do you have it in document_root?
Don't use this method. This is incorrectly.

Use Wordpress AJAX method - get more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Not sure about $wpdb object, as it works in a different php file. Yes, this is my complete getVal.php. It's not on document_root, I just didn't post the like here, but if, for example, I use "echo" in this file, it works just fine. I will try to use what you suggested.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by using a different way to connect to DB.
Did it using this code:

```
require_once("wp-load.php");
$link = new wpdb("***", "***", "***", "***");
```

Everything else stayed the same.